# pyplot - what does iloc do in this code snippet

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Yes, I read the documentation on pyplot's website. No, it still doesn't make sense.

What does the following code snippet do?  I think it's reading in the first 100 lines of a dataset, but not sure what it does regarding the columns:

```py
# select setosa and versicolor
    y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
    y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)

    # extract sepal length and petal length
    X = df.iloc[0:100, [0, 2]].values

    # plot data
    plt.scatter(X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1],
                color='red', marker='o', label='setosa')
    plt.scatter(X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1],
                color='blue', marker='x', label='versicolor')

    plt.xlabel('sepal length [cm]')
    plt.ylabel('petal length [cm]')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line `y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values` is taking the first 100 rows (as you know), and the 5th (index 4) column. And the `.values` on the end is converting that to a numpy arrray, rather than a pandas series.

the line `X = df.iloc[0:100, [0, 2]].values` is again taking the first 100 rows, and the first and third (index 0 and 2) columns, and again converting it to an array. This one gives us a 100x2 array since we chose two columns, which I think is why the author used a capital `X` for the variable name, compared to a lower case `y` for the `100x1` array from the first step.

The third section, this line:

```
plt.scatter(X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1],
                color='red', marker='o', label='setosa')
```

makes a scatter plot with the first 50 rows of `X`, where the first column is the horizontal position and the second column is the vertical position. The next line:

```
plt.scatter(X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1],
                color='blue', marker='x', label='versicolor')
```

is doing the same thing with the bottom half (rows 50-100) of `X`. If you're running this code and nothing is happening, try adding `plt.show()` at the end.